Stuck in Google PubSub Subscription for Google Meet
I am trying to establish Google Pub/Sub using target resource.
Refer: https://developers.google.com/workspace/events#supported-events
When I try to subscribe the resource using python LINK  it fails to subscribe by target resource.
The Syntax for target resource is //cloudidentity.googleapis.com/users/USER_ID
I don't know how to get USER_ID to make it work, I just used my email address but I am stuck in below error.

Permission denied on target resource //cloudidentity.googleapis.com/users/myemailaddress@gmail.com, or the target resource doesn't exist.
I am trying to establish Google Pub/Sub using target resource to register all google meet notifications like joined meet, ended, recordings ready, transcripts ready.
I am refering thsi docs: https://developers.google.com/workspace/events#supported-events

Subscribing by User ID is too difficult maybe unknown.
Finally tried using space_id after trial and error and found out I must generate the SPACE_ID using Python library or by sending HTTP request to:
https://meet.googleapis.com/v2/spaces/{GOOGLE-MEET-CODE}  GOOGLE-MEET-CODE = abc-hijk-xyz
From above http request get the space_id and subscribe using space resource:
//meet.googleapis.com/spaces/SPACE_ID  //meet.googleapis.com/spaces/cZ-XRuSTmQAB
This works!! later subscribe via webhooks or listen using python library through gRPC
